# Change compound token default behaviour in lucene/elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, token, decomposition

Lucene/elasticsearch provide a possibility of compound tokens / subtokens. This is an important feature for e.g. German with composed words. The default behaviour of lucene is to combine the subtokens with an `OR` in order to not hurt recall and exclude documents from being returned. In specific situations, however, the opposite is required.

Assume that I want to index the following two documents:

Document 1:

```
PUT /idxwith/_doc/1
{
  "name": "stockfisch"
}
```

Document 2:

```
PUT /idxwith/_doc/2
{
  "name" : "laufstock"
}
```

Where the words will be decomposed as follows:

```
stockfisch  ==> stock, fisch
laufstock   ==> lauf, stock
```

Now with the following search query:

```
POST /idxwith/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "stockfisch"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd expect only the first document to be returned - which is not the case. As the subtokens are combined with `OR`, both documents will be returned (hurting the precision of my search):

```
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "idxwith",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.3287766,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "stockfisch"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idxwith",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.241631,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "laufstock"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I'm looking for hints on how to adapt lucene (or elastic) to make this behaviour configurable, i.e. to be able to define that subtokens are combined with an `AND` if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you can use matchphrase query like this:

```
POST /idxwith/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name": {
        "query": "stockfisch"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A phrase query matches terms up to a configurable slop (which defaults to 0) in any order. Transposed terms have a slop of 2. for more info about MatchPhrase check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html).

It is also possbile to use Operator in match query that it means all terms should be in term, more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

In your specific case I think Match_Phrase is a much better option since the order of terms are important.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've had a look at the ngrams token filter and it behaves exactly as I'd wish the decompounder to behave, i.e. it is possible to define whether the tokens are `OR`ed or `AND`ed. Do you have an idea how to achieve this, i.e. how to change the lucene decompounder to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: @paweloque, you can add Ngram token filter to your analyzer. for more info check here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html